# How to import the library function "import can" in Python

Tags: python, installation, importerror

I am using Ubuntu. I want to spam the bus and view the packets using Wireshark. I tried to run the Python code shown below, but it threw the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'can'
```

My code:

```py
import time, can
bustype = 'socketcan'
channel = 'vcan0'
def producer(id):
    # :param id: Spam the bus with messages including the data id.
    bus = can.interface.Bus(channel=channel, bustype=bustype)
    for i in range(10):
        msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=0xc0ffee, data=[id, i, 0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1], extended_id=False)
        bus.send(msg)
    # Issue #3: Need to keep running to ensure the writing threads stay alive. 
    time.sleep(1)
producer(10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Ubuntu 18.04 and later

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later python-can and python3-can are provided by the default Ubuntu repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install python3-can # for Python 3.x
```

or

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install python python-can # for Python 2.x
```

To install CANard (Library for interacting with Controller Area Network (CAN)) you must use pip.

```
python3 -m pip install --user CANard # for Python 3.x
```

or

```
python -m pip install --user CANard # for Python 2.x
```

Comment: I am getting a similar error (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'canard')when I type the following "from canard import can" how can i resolve it ?

Comment: @annonymous I replied to your comment by adding the code so that `from canard import can` works to my answer. I tested it on Python 3.6.5 in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you get the `no module named '<module_name>' error` in Python, it means that python can not find the module. Likely because module is missing.

You can install python modules using pip. 
If you don't have the pip tool then you can install it using `sudo apt install python-pip` on Debian based operating systems.

In your case you need [python-can](https://pypi.org/project/python-can/) module which can be install by using

`pip install python-can`

Answer (score 0):

You need to [install external third-party package ***python-can***](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.0/installation.html)
You can do so using pip. Follow the instructions in the provided link