# ImportError: No module named canard

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the canard lib's example given [here](https://pypi.org/project/CANard/)

```
from canard import can
from canard.hw import cantact

dev = cantact.CantactDev("/dev/cu.usbmodem14511")

dev.start()
while True:
      print(dev.recv())
```

I have installed the lib via the pip command and can see it when I execute `pip list`. However, when I execute the above program, I get the error - `ImportError: No module named canard` Any reason why this might be happening? I'm on ubuntu.

`pip freeze` output -

```
appdirs==1.4.4
apturl==0.5.2
bcrypt==3.1.7
blinker==1.4
Brlapi==0.7.0
CANard==0.2.2
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
chrome-gnome-shell==0.0.0
Click==7.0
colorama==0.4.3
command-not-found==0.3
cryptography==2.8
cupshelpers==1.0
dbus-python==1.2.16
defer==1.0.6
distlib==0.3.1
distro==1.4.0
distro-info===0.23ubuntu1
duplicity==0.8.12.0
entrypoints==0.3
.......
.......
```

Comment: The most probable reason is that your `python` executable is not related to your `pip` executable. Try running `python -m pip install ...` instead, so you're sure to use the same interpreter for installing things. Better yet, create a virtualenv (search for instructions).

Comment: Welcome to SO.   How are you running the script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import the library function "import can" in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627795/how-to-import-the-library-function-import-can-in-python)

Comment: Can you run `pip freeze` and post the output here, please?

Comment: do you have multiple versions of python? Show us how you execute your program and the exact steps of your installation :)

Comment: @TharunK unfortunately, that did not help.

Comment: @Sylvain I just write 'python filename.py' on my terminal.

Comment: @AKX setting up a virtualenv did not help

Comment: to know which python and which pip you are using, type `which python`, and `which pip` in your terminal

Comment: Do `pip --version` at a console prompt  and `sys.version` at a Python interpreter prompt and compare the results. It is likely that your `pip` is installing the module in a different instance of Python than the one you expect.

Comment: try to specify your python version by using `python3 script.py` and `python3 -m pip ...`. Check which python you are using (`which python`, `which pip`), as recommended by the others